# Need better solution for 2018 AMC 12B #23

Tags: geometry, contest-math, 3d, spherical-coordinates

I am practicing for the AMC 12 competitions which are in about a week or 2, so when I was taking the 2018 AMC 12B as practice, I came across this problem:

> Ajay is standing at point $A$ near Pontianak, Indonesia, $0^\circ$ latitude and $110^\circ \text{ E}$ longitude. Billy is standing at point $B$ near Big Baldy Mountain, Idaho, USA, $45^\circ \text{ N}$ latitude and $115^\circ \text{ W}$ longitude. Assume that Earth is a perfect sphere with center $C$. What is the degree measure of $\angle ACB$?
>
> $$\textbf{(A) }105 \qquad
> \textbf{(B) }112\frac{1}{2} \qquad
> \textbf{(C) }120 \qquad
> \textbf{(D) }135 \qquad
> \textbf{(E) }150 \qquad$$

The solutions I have found so far are [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2018_AMC_12B_Problems/Problem_23) and [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c5h1593038_fear_the_sphere) on the AoPS website, but I didn't really understand/like the solutions that were provided and I haven't seen a single diagram for the problem, so can someone provide a solution that is easier to understand (preferably without vectors or matrices) or at least a diagram to help me visualize the solutions better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the radius of the earth as 1. $A,C$ lie in the plane containing the equator. Project $B$ onto that plane to give a point $B'$. The angle $ACB'$ is $135^\circ$ ($=360^\circ-110^\circ-115^\circ$). $AC=1,CB'=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ (because $B$ is at latitude $45^\circ$). So by the cosine formula we find $AB'=\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}$.

The triangle $AB'B$ has a right angle at $B'$. So the hypotenuse $AB=\sqrt3$.

Now the triangle $ABC$ is isosceles with $AB=\sqrt3$ and $AC=BC=1$. So $\sin\frac{1}{2}ACB=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$ and hence $\frac{1}{2}ACB=60^\circ$ and so $\angle ACB=120^\circ$.

[image]